# new to android - how to use the 'uploadImage' method found in SocialAuthAdapter class

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am trying to upload an image to twitter. [SocialAuthAdapter class](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/source/browse/trunk/socialauth-android/src/org/brickred/socialauth/android/SocialAuthAdapter.java?r=319) contains an 'uploadImage' method which should do it.

Here is my code:

```
public void post_image(){ 
File imgFile = new  File("/storage/sdcard0/pic_app/ubgthyghu.com2013923.png");
bitmap2 = decodeFile(imgFile); //this just brings back a resized bitmap, it works.. i  tested it
try {
Log.d(tag,"********************* picture is going to be updated...");
int returnvalue  = adapter.uploadImage("fred", "ubgthyghu.com2013923.png", bitmap2, 3);
Log.d(tag,"here is the return value:  " + returnvalue );
} catch (Exception e) {Log.d(tag,"u got an error haus");  e.printStackTrace();}
}//post_image
```

however i get the following message back:

```
09-27 07:39:16.280: D/ShareButtonActivity(11622): ********************* picture is going to be updated...
09-27 07:39:16.400: D/dalvikvm(11622): GC_CONCURRENT freed 424K, 10% free 12775K/14151K, paused 11ms+1ms, total 19ms
09-27 07:39:16.400: D/dalvikvm(11622): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 7ms
09-27 07:39:16.400: I/TwitterImpl(11622): Uploading Image :: ubgthyghu.com2013923.png, message :: fred
09-27 07:39:16.405: D/ShareButtonActivity(11622): u got an error haus
09-27 07:39:16.405: W/System.err(11622): org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: Image Upload Error
09-27 07:39:16.405: W/System.err(11622): at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter.uploadImage(SocialAuthAdapter.java:1137)
09-27 07:39:16.405: W/System.err(11622): at com.example.twitter_stuff.ShareButtonActivity.post_image(ShareButtonActivity.java:273)
09-27 07:39:16.405: W/System.err(11622): at com.example.twitter_stuff.ShareButtonActivity$ResponseListener$1.onClick(ShareButtonActivity.java:171)
09-27 07:39:16.405: W/System.err(11622): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
09-27 07:39:16.405: W/System.err(11622): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17281)
09-27 07:39:16.405: W/System.err(11622): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-27 07:39:16.405: W/System.err(11622): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-27 07:39:16.405: W/System.err(11622): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-27 07:39:16.405: W/System.err(11622): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
09-27 07:39:16.405: W/System.err(11622): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 07:39:16.410: W/System.err(11622): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-27 07:39:16.410: W/System.err(11622): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
09-27 07:39:16.410: W/System.err(11622): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
09-27 07:39:16.410: W/System.err(11622): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-27 07:39:16.440: D/SocialAuthError(11622): org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: Failed to update status on http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=hjjhhj. Status :403
09-27 07:39:16.440: D/ShareButton(11622): Authentication Error: Message Not Posted
09-27 07:39:16.455: D/SocialAuthError(11622): org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: Failed to update status on http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=hjjhhj. Status :403
09-27 07:39:16.455: D/ShareButton(11622): Authentication Error: Message Not Posted
```

I know that is quite messy to ready - sorry but the main code from it which needs to be fixed is this:

```
int returnvalue  = adapter.uploadImage("fred", "ubgthyghu.com2013923.png", bitmap2, 3);
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue ? I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `adapter.uploadImageAsync`
You are implicity performing a `http` action on the `main ui threat`. Android doesnt like that